# Select Radio Button Using Javascript with No ID

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web, applescript

I am trying to select a radio button on a webpage using Javascript inside an Applescript. For this particular button, there is no element ID, so I'm no really sure how to select this radio button.

There's really no other identifying elements for this form (or that I see, at least).

*Note:* There's several radio buttons on this page, and the only unique identifier between them is the "value."

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" size="4" name="Level" value="p;29">
```

**Javascript/Applescript:**

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementById('p;29').checked = true;" in doc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the `value` and `name` fields to target the element and check it. Here is the working script:

```
do JavaScript "var elements = document.getElementsByName('Level');
for (i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
  if(elements[i].value == 'p;29') {
    elements[i].checked = true;
  }
}" in doc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have no other input elements, you can safely use

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]
```

Otherwise, you can do:

```
for (i=0; i<document.getElementsByTagName('input').length; i++) {
    var myInput = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i];
    if (myInput.type == 'radio')
    {
      //myInput is the radio element. Do something with it
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to just script that line of the HTML and add `checked` at the end?

Comment: Yes, but that was not your question. Just do a google search on how to add `checked` attribute to an element.